# Highlight a text Qt

Tags: qt

everyone. 
I have a text written on my textEdit. When I click a button, I want to highlight the text with a background color, without loosing the information about the font, the color ect. 
I've tried with the following code:

```
QTextCursor curs=ui->textEdit->textCursor();
QTextCharFormat fmt=curs.charFormat();
fmt.setBackground(Qt::yellow);
curs.setCharFormat(fmt);
ui->textEdit->setTextCursor(curs);
```

but it doesn't work. 
Can you help me? 
Thanks

Comment: I've changed my code:

Comment: The solution doesn't work, because it highlights the text, but it changes the color and the properties

Comment: I flag this question to reopen

Comment: Answer for you: `QTextCharFormat newFmt; newFmt.setBackground(Qt::yellow);  curs.mergeCharFormat(newFmt);` see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#mergeCharFormat